# How to perform query in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I need to filter the a particular user's bar in whcih reservations were made. I am a beginner in Django and have tried some methods which unfortunately didn't work.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)

class Bar(models.Model):

    user_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Tables(models.Model):

    table_no = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=False)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(to=Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.table_no


class Reservation(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    table = models.ForeignKey(Tables, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

**Note**: I wan to filter the reservations made in a particular user's bar

Answer (score 0):

I know you might be having a hard time and its one the things you go through when you are learning..

1.Can you change this first

**from**

class Bar(models.Model):

```
user_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**To**

class Bar(models.Model):

```
user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

2.On querying your data can you can try this since our user will already on the bar

user_bar = Bar.objects.filter("Here you specify what you wanna filter by")

**Or**

user_bar = Bar.objects.get(id=pk)

Comment: Thanks for the kind help mate.

Comment: when you used id=pk.

Is the pk defined, what did you mean by that

Answer (score 0):

When I used this query filter. it worked perfectly.

```
reservations = Reservation.objects.filter(table__bar__user_id=request.user)
```

**subject title**: People can come to the restaurant and book a reservation filling a form which uses the Reservation model. Then the reservation is connected to a Table which is connected to a bar and the owner of the bar. Now I need to be able to filter the reservations made in each bar owner restaurant.